# Do all bases release OH-?

Tags: acid-base

Do all bases release OH-? Do all bases have the ability to receive an H+ ion? As an example, CaCO3 is a base but it doesn't release OH- ions.

PS. I am a high school student

Comment: What definition of acidity are you using? There are more than one.

Comment: Depends on what solvent they are in.

Comment: $\ce{CaCO3}$  can react with acids, but it is not a base

Comment: Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions without hints of solving attempt are usually frown upon and often closed on the StackExchange network.  OTOH, well elaborated questions have higher probability to  receive acceptable answers.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Maurice CaCO3 is an Usanovich base, providing negative anion for the reaction.

Comment: @Poutnik. $\ce{CaCO3}$ contains a base, namely the ion $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$. But it is not a base itself.

Comment: @Maurice It depends on the base definition which depends on the applied acid-base theory. I do agree it is not a base according to the 3 usual acid-base theories. I also agree Usanovich theory is rather obscure one and I have not seen it used in practice. E.g. NaOH(s) is a base by Arrhenius and Usanovich theories, but not by Brønsted-Lowry nor Lewis theories (OH- is). For Usanovich theory,  CaCO3 or Na2O are bases too. There is also a Lux–Flood theory, used in geology or for molten salts, considering as a base the source of O^2- anion.

Comment: @Poutnik. Never heard of this Usanovitch theory. Is it important to develop it here ? Why do you mention a nearly unknown theory to a high school student, who is probably in his first year of chemistry ? I am not sure it will help him a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142636/discussion-between-poutnik-and-maurice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Not all bases directly release $\ce{OH-}$ ion, but in case of water solutions, their chemical interactions lead finally to increasing of $\ce{OH-}$ concentration.*

It was originally thought all bases are hydroxides, releasing hydroxide ion.(Arrhenius)

It was later realized not only hydroxides cause alkalinity, so acids and bases were redefined in sense of proton ($\ce{H+(aq)}$ in water) exchange (Brønsted-Lowry, B-L). It is not limited to water solvent nor even to liquids, being applicable to solids or gases as well.

$$\ce{NH3 + H2O <=> NH4+ + OH-}$$
$$\ce{CO3^2- + H2O <=> HCO3- + OH-}$$

So ammonia does not release hydroxide ion, but captures proton from water. $\ce{CaCO3(s)}$ either releases carbonate anion that is a B-L base, or is able to capture $\ce{H+}$ itself.
Similarly for solid $\ce{NaOH}$.

$$\ce{CaCO3(s) + 2 H+(aq) -> Ca^2+(aq) + CO2(g) + H2O(l)}$$

This should be enough for you for now, the rest is left for optional further reading.

---

There are several developed [theories of acids and bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Usanovich_definition), each being more general and involving older ones.

Bases by the Arrhenius acid-base theory release $\ce{OH-}$ ion. Like solid $\ce{NaOH}$ when dissolved.

Bases by the Brønsted-Lowry acid-base theory capture a proton like $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{H2O}$ or $\ce{CO3^2-}$. It is applicable for all gaseous, solid and liquid phases, not limited to water solutions.

Bases by the Lewis acid-base theory donate an electron pair, like in prior paragraph, or $\ce{NH3}$ reacting with  $\ce{BF}$ (a Lewis acid, accepting an electron pair). This remove the prior limitation to the proton exchange.

[image]

(image credit to [Wikimedia Commons User Riptide360](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Riptide360)).

There are therefore often used terms "Arrhenius base", "Brønsted-Lowry base", "Lewis base".

---

There are even more general and complex acid-base theories in the link above, but that would be out of the needed knowledge scope

Answer (score 0):

No, NH3 is a base. NH3 contains no oxygen - no hydroxide ions - so it cannot release hydroxide ions when dissolved in aqueous solution. I think you are getting the terms alkali and base mixed up - all alkalis contain hydroxide ions - they release them in aqueous solution - so all alkalis are bases but not all bases are alkalis.

Do all bases have the ability to receive H+ ions? Yes - the definition of a base is

> a substance that can accept hydrogen ions in water and can neutralize an acid

So all bases have the ability to receive hydrogen cations (H+ ions) - or "protons" as some chemists call them - you may have heard the term "acid donates a proton" - that's speak for H+ ions leaving the dissolved acid compound and joining onto a base as part of a neutralisation reaction (acid + base --> salt - plus H2O if the base is an alkali **OR** plus H2O + CO2 if base is a carbonate).

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO general types of chemical reactions. Those involving electron pairs or bonds, the electron pairs change their positions in or between molecules, are Acid-Base reactions. The base furnishes the electron pair the acid accepts it. It can be a subtle interaction or a brute force reaction between a strong acid and strong base in water. This means that a myriad of explanations has been presented to try to describe every nuance. Ignore them and learn Chemistry and the mechanisms for reactions. Acidity and basicity depend on the reaction.

The second general class of reactions involves the actual transfer of electrons usually one at a time. These are known as oxidation-reduction or REDOX reactions. The two usually happen together but can be separated. Unfortunately, these also have a wide range of explanations but usually involve neutral atoms, metals, and elements of differing electronegativity. A further complication is that, with imagination, an acid-base reaction can be written or thought of as a redox reaction and vice-versa.

The solution is to learn the definitions to pass the test, but to look into the overall reactions to try to understand more about what is going on and not be bound to restrictive definitions.